# Failed to load resource file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-alpha.18

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic-cli

I recently updated my Ionic CLI version to 2.0.0-alpha.18 and since then whenever I try to build out my app using Ionic build android, when I run the apk on my device I get this error message:

Failed to load resource file:///android_asset/www/cordova_plugins.js

other info:
Cordova CLI: 5.4.0
Gulp version:  CLI version 3.9.0
Gulp local:   Local version 3.9.0
Ionic Version: 1.1.0
Ionic CLI Version: 2.0.0-alpha.18
Ionic App Lib Version: 2.0.0-alpha.17
OS: Windows 8.1
Node Version: v0.12.7

Anyone else have this problem?

Comment: apparently you don't have `cordova_plugin.js file` , straight up.

Comment: as far as I understand that file is supposed to be included at build time in the build process and you just need to have this include in your index.html file :<script src="cordova.js"></script>

Comment: yes, `cordova.js` not `cordova_plugins.js`. How about reverting back to the latest stable Ionic CLI, which is v1.7.11?

Answer (score 8):

I think I fixed the problem. I had to run: ***ionic platform remove android*** and then ***ionic platform add android*** and then the build worked

Comment: I tried this before coming here and it didn't work for me

Answer (score 1):

try `ionic state reset`. this should restore the plugins and platforms.